# ASP.Net Validation grouping

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to tie the validation of certain controls to one button on an ASP.Net web form and tie the validation of other controls to a different button?  For instance, if I have 6 textboxes (A, B, C, D, E, and F) and two button controls, I'd like to only call the validation on textboxes A, B, and C if button 1 is clicked.  If button 2 is clicked, I'd like to only call the validation on textboxes D, E, and F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) field for each control.  Mark textboxes A, B, C and button 1 as ValidationGroup = 'Group 1', or something similar.  Do the same for textboxes D,E,F and button 2, with a different group name.  This way, only controls with matching group names will be validated when a button with that name is pressed (in your case).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) property of the validators and the controls that causes validation like buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Use [validation groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)